# Debugging in release mode or changing _iterator_debug_level?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am working with a checked-out Visual Studio C++ Project originally built in VS 2006. I want to put in breakpoints to see where certain functions are called and better follow the workflow.

I rebuilt the code in Visual Studio 2010 in Release mode, and it builds and runs well. Unfortunately, from some research, I have learned that some of the breakpoints cannot be hit in Release mode and I need to build the code in Debug mode to hit the breakpoints.

However, when I try to build the code in Debug mode, the linker complains about the .lib files having the wrong _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL. Is there a way that I can change this _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL in the .libs so I can build it in debug mode? If not, is there any way to hit these breakpoints in Release mode or ReleaseWithDebug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw this article from Hansleman recently:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DebugVsReleaseTheBestOfBothWorlds.aspx

It basically says you can compile for optimizations (Release) and debug without recompile (Debug) using a combination of debug settings and an ini file.

Comment: Thank you - I'm trying to follow those steps. I've done some research but I'm not sure what it means to emit debug symbols - does that mean to create or find .pdbs? And where can I do that in my project properties? I have tried adding Symbol file locations in Debug > Options and Settings > Debugging > Symbols, but I haven't been able to find all of the .pdbs

Comment: The pdbs are normally generated when you build the project. I'm looking at C# properties so it might be different in C++ properties but I go to the Build tab and then Advanced and make sure that 'Debug info' full is selected. Usually this is selected for you when the Debug configuration is chosen.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up just converting settings similar to the article you gave so I can debug in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

**You can debug C++ in release mode by configuring the projects Properties Pages as follows:**

> 1. Under C/C++ node -> General node. 
>      Set "Debug Information Format" to "C7 compatible (/Z7)" or "Program
>      Database (/Zi)".
> 2. Under Linker node -> General node. Set "Enable Incremental Linking" to "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)".
> 3. Under the Linker node -> Debugging node. Set "Generate Debug Info" to "Yes (/DEBUG)".
> 4. Under Linker node -> Optimization node. Set "References" to "/OPT:REF"
> 5. Under Linker node -> Optimization node. Set "Enable COMDAT Folding" to "/OPT:ICF".

You can now debug and step through the code in your release build application.

*Note: When setting the properties make sure you have selected the correct configuration and platform (the combo-boxes at the top of the properties pages)*